# To get only 64 bit JRE value from Windows Registry

Tags: java, registry

As i am from testing background and have a very limited knowledge on Java kindly excuse me if the question i have asked is not good or repetitive.

I am trying to build an application using Java Swing. As per the requirement I have to display 32 bit Jre or 64 bit Jre installed on laptop based on the selection made. [Frame which i developed for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkCRE.png)

Unfortunately when I tested by installing a 32 bit JRE on Windows 64 bit machine  and tried to run my application, when I choose the radio button "64 bit JRE" , in the drop down list its displaying me the 32 bit JRE which is installed on my system. (Kindly note i do not have any 64 bit JRE installed on my system). Ideally it should not display anything but the default value set in the JComboBox. :(

I understood the JRE was picked due to the Windows property. I tried with the API Advapi32.INSTANCE using the method RegGetValue but i am unable to get the value from Windows Registry.

32 bit JRE are under the path : **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node \JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment** 
and 64 bit JRE are under the path : **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment**

Please find the below code which i tried to retrieve 64 bit JRE :

```
String[] val64 = RegistryCheck.getRegistryDataForJRE(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment"); 

public static String[] getRegistryDataForJRE(WinReg.HKEY root, String key) {

    if (Advapi32Util.registryKeyExists(root, key)) {
        return Advapi32Util.registryGetKeys(root, key);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also below is the code which i tried with  Advapi32.INSTANCE (just ttried to do a sysout to know whether the value returned is 0 or not. as from the Microsoft pages i see if its a non zero value returned its an error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte[] b = new byte[50];
    IntByReference pcbData = new IntByReference(50);

    System.out.println(Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment",
        "" , 0x0200, pcbData, b, pcbData));

}
```

Also, I read the flag **KEY_WOW64_32KEY**  is the responsible to pick up from the **WOW6432Node** , but i am not able to check the flag value or to set it to false in java.

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

I would be really grateful for the help.

Thank you in advance for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the method RegOpenKeyEx() of Advapi32 i.e. syntax

```
RegOpenKeyEx(WinReg.HKEY hKey,
                 String lpSubKey,
                 int ulOptions,
                 int samDesired,
                 WinReg.HKEYByReference phkResult)
```

refer to the link [RegOpenKeyEx()](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.html#RegOpenKeyEx-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY-java.lang.String-int-int-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEYByReference-)

You can pass the parameters accordingly and then check if the return value is "0" then the path exists in 64 bit else it doesn't exists.

Note : when you pass "samDesired" into the RegOpenKeyEx() pass the combination of KEY_QUERY_VALUE and KEY_WOW64_64KEY

For example :

```
WinReg.HKEYByReference hKey = new HKEYByReference();
Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment",0,  0x0001 | 0x0100,  hKey);
```

Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: Thank you...the solution worked for me :) thanks a lot

Comment: No problem :) Happy to help